# Change logo on the custom web form

Tags: stripe-payments

How to replace this green icon with my custom logo?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have searched this seconds but add `data-image = "/dir/of/image/here.jpg"` to the script

Comment: Thanks, but of course I searched before asking. "custom stripe form logo" and a dozen of similar searches.

Comment: No probs. Their documentation is pretty in depth and is really useful for simple stuff like this. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: It's helpful to your cause to add proof of work to the question.